# Send data to websocket connections on a timer or RDS event

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sockets, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I am creating a web socket using AWS for live tracking of a trip. Every user can track their trip online. So have created web socket API  in AWS which calls a lambda function to serve a connection. Lambda function will give a result from DB based on unique ID passed by client. 
I want to call a lambda function every 5 seconds or generate an event of RDS server on change in table. 
How can I achieve this?
Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into either possibility yet? What was the conclusion?

Comment: I have searched for setting time interval in lambda function it is not possible is what i understand. Please correct if wrong

Comment: You can schedule recurring Lambdas through EventBridge, but the minimum rate is 1 minute. You could get around that if you *really* wanted - for example one lambda could become a scheduler which is invoked by EventBridge every 5 minutes, and that lambda in turn invokes your websocket lambda every 5 seconds for 5 minutes. Not that I'm suggesting this but it is possible. In my opinion it would be preferable to use RDS events if at all possible. I should say, I looked into implementing a data-change-triggered websocket API using PG RDS, and while possible it's not really viable at this point.

Comment: Ok but I have to send different response to different connections based on ID is that possible ?